# problem with index type's string with object

Tags: typescript, object, generics

I have a problem to use index in a object , my code work in Js but not in TS. 
I have this error :
*Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'objectInt'.
 No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'objectInt'.*

My code:

```
interface objectInt {
    name: {
        firstname: string;
        lastname: string;
    };

    data?: string;
    height?: string;
}

let person: objectInt = {
    name: {
        firstname: "Jean",
        lastname: "Martin",
    }

};

let data: string = 'height';
let value: string = '1.75m';
person[data] = value;

console.log(person.height); //1.75m
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This derives from you typing `data` as `string`, TypeScript will need `data` to be of type `'height' | 'data'` in order to match how you use it here `person[data] = value`. You could e.g. solve this by:

```
interface objectInt {
    name: {
        firstname: string;
        lastname: string;
    };

    data?: string;
    height?: string;
}

let person: objectInt = {
    name: {
        firstname: "Jean",
        lastname: "Martin",
    },
    height:''
};

const data: 'height' | 'data' = 'height';
let value: string = '1.75m';
person[data] = value;
```

Comment: thank you, that work, i just took of `height :''`  in the object.